# How to view an uploaded image in react in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react frontend, and I want to view the image on the browser when I upload the image.
Below is my uploading function

```
onDrop = async (files) => {

    const FILES = {
        "uploaded_image": [{
            name: files[0].name, <- Name prints on screen succesfully
            image: files[0].file, <- It is just empty
        }]
    }

    this.setState({
          ...some states
    })
   ..some calls
}
```

And below is the render

```
<div>
     <Image
     src={this.state.files[0].image}
     />
 </div>
```

The image shows if I hardcode the field directly,

```
image: require(`static_media/car.png`).default
```

But I would like to show without hardcoding the path of the uploaded file, how can I modify the `image field` in the `onDrop` to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use URL.createObjectURL(files[0])

```
 const FILES = {
    "uploaded_image": [{
        name: files[0].name, <- Name prints on screen succesfully
        image: URL.createObjectURL(files[0]), <- It is just empty
    }]
}
```